# Convert SQL Server Query to MongoDB Query @ Runtime

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb

I am in a situation where I need to convert my dynamically generated SQL Server query to Mongo DB query. Is there any tool/plugin/nuget package available that takes sql server query as input and outputs mongodb query(just like what is done in "www.querymongo.com")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No

I would add than you don't send interpreted language (sql) than you can adapt according to the database server, but you use a proprietary API :

http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/

Comment: I am creating the query from dynamic controls on my page (in javascript), so LINQ might not help.

Comment: ? I dont get it. Both sql statements and linq statements are issued by the server, not by client side.

Comment: Ok, so I am building the query on UI, mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder  See this link for an example.

I have to take what user selects, and based on it get the results from DB

Comment: Then I would advise to parse the generated WHERE clause on the server side, get a set of criterias and use thoses criterias for querying mongodb.
You may have a look at a basic sqlparser than I wrote for a jqgrid filtering feature, the server was using c# and Subsonic orm. The problematic was similar (even if I finally get rid of subsonic) :

http://codepaste.net/utbrdg

Comment: I would also suggest to stay with a RDBMS (Relational DataBase Management System) unless you *absolutly* have to use a non relational (nosql) sql engine.

Answer (score 0):

Have created a JS for creating the Mongo queries dynamically, based on the operators selected.